# How do I save the viewport bitmap of an imageview? - Android

Tags: android, android-imageview

I only want to save the bitmap of the image being displayed/cropped in the ImageView.

When I call this, it returns the entire bitmap:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to get the bitmap from ImageView

```
imageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();
```